# Android Failed to verify CA certificate from passpoint profile

Tags: android, certificate, wifi, android-wifi

I am currently trying to download a passpoint profile from a website which will kick off the installation of a passpoint profile onto a given Android device.

I have generated a profile which includes all of the relevant information for the passpoint network itself however when it comes to the certificate Android throws the following error in logcat.

`E/PasspointManager: Failed to verify CA certificate: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors`

I can confirm that my profile containing the network information such as realm and FQDN does work as using it with someone else's certificate successfully installs on Android.

Can anyone explain why the certificate would fail to install via the profile and not when installing it via Android settings?

Comment: Are you working with R1 or R2? How did you install your profile? Through OSU server (R2) or downloading it?

Comment: There is a chain of certs, right.  Root being the highest ranking. I ran into a similar issue where I had to include the next ranking CA or the one above the client CA I was using. 

A reference to that cert was added in the actual CA itself - not code. It worked after that.  Not required for iOS but for some reason it is for Android.

Comment: @AleksandarZoric I am referring to this link https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-passpoint#file_composition where it says X.509 CA certificate is mandatory for TTLS. How do you create this certificate? Is this something you need to create, for example, at the RADIUS server for a given user that was created which is going to use Hotspot 2.0 enabled network?

Comment: @Quirik Exactly it.  That is the root CA which lives on the RADIUS server, and this cert must follow the full chain of certificates. Now from what I can recall, iOS uses on the onboard CA but this is required for Android. 

However, for TLS - the client certificate is required for both OS's. 
When I was working on this, somebody else created that CA and put it on the RADIUS - so not sure how the CA is created

Comment: @AleksandarZoric Could you please explain which certificate must be included in the Passpoint profile, and which certificate must be inluded on RADIUS server? What is the purpose of certificate in Passpoint profile?